# How to convert "for loop" to "apply family functions"

Tags: r, vectorization, apply, lag

My data frame looks like this. (it has ~ 300,000 rows)
I want to do this operation faster and elegantly. 
How can i overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
df <- data.frame(
   X = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T),
   Y = sample(10:20, 10, replace = T)
 )

for (i in 2:(nrow(df)))
{
   if (df$X[i] == 0)
   {
      df$X[i] = df$Y[i - 1]
   }
}
```

Comment: This is called *"vectorization"*. As in *"How to vectorize this lag calculation?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try `lag`

```
df$X <- ifelse(df$X == 0, lag(df$Y), df$X)
```

If we need to ignore the first row

```
df[2:nrow(df), ] <- with(df[2:nrow(df), ], ifelse(X == 0, lag(Y), X))
```

Comment: What if we have 2 assignments in "if" statement ? Does "ifelse" work similarly ?

Comment: @xfactor I am not sure if I get you completely. However, mostly if we want to assign values to another column then we need to write another similar line of code.